# Keep Binance futures wss alive

Tags: sockets, websocket, bitcoin, trading, binance

I have this code :

```
startWss();
function startWss(){
let  wsBinance = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binancefuture.com/stream?streams=btcusdt@bookTicker', { 
    apiKeyID: testApiKeys[0], 
    apiKeySecret: testApiSecrets[0] 
});

if(wsBinance){
    wsBinance.on('error', () => { console.error });
    wsBinance.on('open', () => { console.log('Connection opened bookTicker.') } );
    wsBinance.on('close', function () {
        startWss();
        console.log('Connection closed bookTicker.');
    } );
    wsBinance.on('initialize', () => console.log('Client initialized, data is flowing.' ));
    wsBinance.onmessage = e => {

        let dataJson = JSON.parse(e.data)
        if(dataJson.data){
            priceA= dataJson.data.b
            priceB= dataJson.data.a
        }
    }
}
```

}

But it closes after some time. How do I keep it always running?
I thought it should work by restarting it in close but its not working..

Comment: [The websocket server will send a ping frame every 3 minutes. If the websocket server does not receive a pong frame back from the connection within a 10 minute period, the connection will be disconnected. Unsolicited pong frames are allowed.](https://binanceapitest.github.io/Binance-Future-API-test-doc/wss/)

Comment: any code to do pong?

Comment: i have the same issue here, i can't seem to send just the raw string 'pong', i will receive an error. Any guidelines?

Answer (score -1):

You may need to periodically ping (or send a pong in response to the ping) the server to indicate the connection is still alive.

Understand that this is at a connection level rather than the application level (i.e. this is not part of the stream path given by Binance, but at the websocket level itself)

The code will depend on your websocket framework of choice: some may automatically process the ping and emit a pong, but it may not be happening in you framework.

Basically, on receiving a Ping from the server (check you event handlers to identify this) you will need to send back a "Pong", potentially with the same payload that was send in the ping frame.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.3 for the RFC related to this. The opcode for a pong is 0xA.